# Grails Asset Pipeline: URLs with cache digest in file name within static assets

Tags: html, grails, asset-pipeline, gsp

I'm using the Grails Asset Pipeline 2.2.5 plugin on Grails 2.5.0 (the current 2.x version for both).

I am serving static HTML, JS, CSS, and image files from Amazon S3 (might move to CloudFront later, but that shouldn't affect this question), and I serve REST endpoints backed by controllers from my Grails servers.

If, e.g., I have a static HTML asset that includes an `img` element whose `src` attribute value is a URL to a static image asset, how can I make the URL include the correct cache digest fingerprint in the file name?

I shouldn't have to run any Groovy / Java / JavaScript at runtime to get correct URLs including cache digests; I should be able to calculate them at build time, and somehow write out URLs in the static files at build time including the cache digests.

Will any of the following work? Each option is followed by an example of what pre-build code would look like. For all of the options, for a cache digest `1234567890abcdef`, the output should be:

```
<img src="abc-1234567890abcdef.jpg"/>
```

1. Is Asset Pipeline smart enough to find static asset URLs in HTML and automatically rewrite them?  I've verified that Asset Pipeline will rewrite relative URLs in CSS files, and insert cache digests in the file names, but I haven't found a way to get it to rewrite URLs in HTML files.

   ```
   <img src="abc.jpg"/>
   ```
2. Is there a placeholder that I can add to HTML to have Asset Pipeline automatically insert the cache digest?

   ```
   <img src="abc%cache-digest-placeholder%.jpg"/>
   ```
3. Can I use some other format, like GSP or [GTPL](https://grails.org/plugin/groovy-template-grails-asset-pipeline) (though GTPL seems to only work for JS & CSS, not HTML), to somehow figure out the URL for the image at build time, rather than at runtime (GSP would normally be evaluated at runtime, but that shouldn't be necessary to determine the cache digest of a static file; it should be known at build time)

   ```
   <img src="${assetPath(src: 'abc.jpg')}"/>
   ```

If it will be difficult to rewrite URLs to include cache digests, how can I turn off inserting cache digests to the names of assets?

Comment: Since you've asked this question about a year ago, did you find any solution in the meantime?

Comment: I just use absolute URLs for everything so that no URL rewriting occurs, and I don't use cache digests at all.  Every time I deploy a new version, I include the version number in the name of the S3 bucket, so all assets are served under new URLs, so no old files are used from browser caches.

Comment: So you're not using the fingerprinting feature and implemented cache busting at a "global level". Hence I assume that the answer to all of your three questions is "no". It's a shame that there is so few information about the (bertramdev/Grails) asset pipeline and especially about the usage at _compile time_, but anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: AP now rewrites relative URLs in HTML in addition to CSS, but it doesn't handle any other files like JS, and it can only rewrite literal URLs; nothing from javascript and/or xhr. I actually modified the Grails 2 AP plugin to allow disabling of digests in URLs. The code was in AP for a bit, but then removed by the main AP author. I've submitted some more patches to clean up AP, and will try to convince the AP dev to include my digest disabling setting. If he won't accept it, I'll maintain a fork.